# What’s the use of 0xff -colors in android?

Tags: android, colors

Sometimes in android projects there are color formats like '0xff4ca665'.

What is the purpose of using them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some programmers come from have more experience with overt 24 bit colors. And sometimes it matters in Android, the alpha isn't masked in some more direct manipulations in renderscript. And as you want '0xff4ca665' telling the system you want '0x4ca665' and hoping something else masks it correctly later on seems like a sketchy bet on something that literally cannot even waste a clock cycle.

Somethings do not take resID links to colors or give you an option like  View.setBackgroundColor(int) where the int for the color is encoded in a 32 bit integer like that.

Specifically this is how alpha masking in 24 bit colors work. They are formatted as a 32 bit integer as 0bAAAAAAAARRRRRRRRGGGGGGGGBBBBBBBB So each color of RGB gets 8 bits and there's 8 bit masking for the alpha done with whatever PorterDuff blending is later used to render the result. Android stores colors purely as integers, so using these is a good idea, if that's what it ends up as.

When you do it in hex like that you get two digits for each thing 0xAARRGGBB and the AA is set to ff meaning 255 or fully opaque. No need to trust the colors to not being fully opaque. There's a lot of times when if you leave those as 00 you end up with a blank image, or well fully transparent one. Knowing which times it matters isn't worth it, if we just overtly include the alpha.

Android also has a few other schemes that matter which store colors in shorts. Namely 4444 which stores alpha and each color in 4 bits. And 565 which stores the red in 5 bits, green in 6 bits and blue in 5 bits. Both of which end up using 16 bits in total rather than 32. But, a great many encoding schemes use 8888 which is pretty standard so it's very common to see people referencing the colors like that, especially in hex.

Comment: There's also the shorter notations `#argb` and `#rgb`, used when the hex are composed by identical numbers (all the components must have this characteristic). So, for instance, `#ff88bbcc` can be rewritten like `#f8bc` or `#8bc`

Comment: Those are actually text based. And while clearly preferred for something, they need to be pushed through the resources which if your operation needs every single clock cycle might not be worth it. As int color = #ffa; will not do anything. If you want that and you don't want to waste even one clock cycle to get it you render that as color = 0xFFFFFFAA

Answer (score 4):

Some android APIs like [View.setBackgroundColor()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor(int)) expect color integers of ARGB format. So `0xff4ca665` denotes the fully opaque RGB color `#4ca665` while the integer `0x4ca665` is equal to `0x004ca665` and therefore denotes the fully transparent color.

Answer (score 2):

Same reason as `#ff4ca665`... To denote an [ARGB color value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space#ARGB_.28word-order.29).

If using the above in the colors XML, the leading `ff` isn't entirely necessary because those are given full opacity.

The `0xff4ca665` would be the equivalent Java representation.

In any case, you get the following color

```css
body {
  background: #4ca665;
}
```

Comment: Specifically, where the first two hex digits represents the alpha: how much transparency to apply to the color.

Comment: The leading `ff` _is_ necessary for the hex representation in Java, which is what the OP is asking about. `0xff4ca665` is not the same as `0x4ca665`, which is transparent.